# How can I calculate $\sin 4x$, I having only $\cos x$?

Tags: trigonometry

This is an exercise in my book:

> Given $\cos(x) = \frac{3}{5}$ find $\sin(4x)$.

How I can calculate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sin 4x = 2\sin 2x \cos 2x = 4\sin x \cos x (2\cos^2 x - 1)$

$\sin x = \pm \sqrt{1-\cos^2 x} = \pm \frac 45$

So $\sin 4x = \pm 4(\frac 45)(\frac 35)(2(\frac 35)^2 - 1) = \mp \frac{336}{625}$

If you were given whether $x$ were in the first or fourth quadrant (only two possibilities with a positive cosine), then you could give a definitive answer. As it stands you need the "$\pm$".

Answer (score 2):

Use $$\sin4x=4\sin{x}\cos{x}\cos2x=4\sin{x}\cos{x}(2\cos^2x-1)$$ and
$$\sin{x}=\pm\frac{4}{5}.$$
I got $$\mp\frac{336}{625}.$$

Comment: That was my first thought, but $\sin x$ wasn't given.

Comment: @Cameron Buie We know that $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$.

Comment: True, but that still leaves ambiguity, as your updated answer makes clear.

Comment: how i can arrive in this formula? I know about sin2x and cos2x, but I don't still get the idea.

Comment: @David Vinicius I used $\sin2\alpha=2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$ and $\cos2\alpha=2\cos^2\alpha-1.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. By the [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)
$$\cos(4x)+i\sin(4x)=(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^4.$$
Hence
$$\sin(4x)=\text{Im}((\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^4)=4\cos^3(x)\sin(x)-4\cos(x)\sin^3(x)\\=4\sin(x)\cos(x)(2\cos^2(x)-1).$$
Finally note that $\sin(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}=\pm \frac 45.$

Comment: That's the formula for $\cos 4x$, not for $\sin 4x$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another Idea : is to use Cebyshev polynomials 
$$\begin{array}{l}
{T_0}(x) = 1\\
{T_1}(x) = x\\
T_2(x)=2xT_1(x)-T_0(x)=2x.x-1=2x^2-1\\
T_3(x)=2xT_2(x)-T_1(x)=2x.(2x^2-1)-x=4x^3-3x\\
T_4(x)=2xT_3(x)-T_2(x)=2x.(4x^3-3x)-(2x^2-1)=\\
{T_{n + 1}}(x) = 2x{T_n}(x) - {T_{n - 1}}(x)
\end{array}$$ when $x\to \cos(nx)$
$$\quad{T_0(x)\to\cos(0x)\\T_1(x)\to\cos(1x)\\T_2(x)\to\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1\\T_3(x)\to4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)}\\$$ can you take over ?